# 2 coins tossed. Probability that both coins are fair, given the frequency of outcomes(HH, TH/HT, TT).

Tags: probability

I toss 2 coins 500 times. I get HH (200 times), TT (100 times), exactly 1 head (200 times). What is the probability that both coins are fair?
Follow up question : Probability that exactly 1 coin is fair?

I am not able to find starting point itself.

Comment: The phrase "probability that both coins are fair" is not particularly meaningful without a prior distribution for the bias of the coin which gives a positive probability to the fairness of the coin.  And at some stage, someone might get suspicious that you had fixed your results to exactly match the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

This might be surprising, but technically speaking, the probability that both coins are perfectly fair is $0$.

In general, a biased coin will have a $p$ probability of landing heads and a $(1-p)$ probability of landing tails.

For a perfectly fair coin, $p=0.5$, exactly.

If there was a finite set of values of $p$, we could use Bayes' theorem and the total probability theorem to calculate the probability that $p=0.5$, but without any additional information in the question, $p$ can take any value in $[0,1]$.

The best we can do is find the probability that $p$ lies a particular small range close to $0.5$, but then too we'll need to do some integral calculus to find out the answer.

Comment: Even then, we'll have to make certain assumptions about the choice of the probability distribution of $p$. All things considered, the question omits critical details about the experiment.

Comment: A nice illustration of this is thinking about distinguishing between a coin that lands on heads $0.5+10^{-10}$ of the time and exactly $0.5$ of the time. It's functionally impossible because after $10^{10}$ tosses the unfair coin lands on heads on average $1$ time - but at the same time, the standard deviation of the number of heads you get is about $50000$.

Answer (score 1):

If the distribution is the limit of the distribution, then this is impossible.

We have

1. $pq=\frac25$
2. $(1-p)(1-q)=1-p-q+pq=\frac15$
3. $p(1-q)+q(1-p)=p+q-2pq=\frac25$

1 and 2 tell us that $p+q=\frac65$, so $5p^2+2=6p$, which only has imaginary roots.